# How can I modify this jsfiddle example to add another row that will stick to the bottom of the big table?

Tags: html, css

[This jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/NnhWZ/3/) is what i got right now, the principle works on a simpler table i need to display but i need to change it a bit for another page. Section 1 will always have the same size, section 2 is of variable size and section 3 should fill the space that's left by section 2. This all works fine and dandy but I have to add another section, let's call it 4, that's of fixed size but always stays at the bottom of the bigger table, right after 3. The height of the big table must always stay the same. The line breaks are there to show what happens when the different tables change size.

I can't use divs or any fancy CSS because of a plug-in that's parsing it but if you got a fancy solution i can maybe make it work. Thanks for your time.

Also, can't use javascript to resize stuff dynamically unfortunately.

Comment: CAn you edit the markup?

Comment: I don't understand why you can't use "fancy css." CSS would not effect the semantics of the html - just the way that html is displayed. It should not effect a parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a job for [tbody and tfoot](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.3) tags along with CSS to control the sizing.